# Eclipse like annotations bar for VStudio C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

I have been using Eclipse for a very long time and I have get used to some of its features.

Eclipse annotations bar, the small bar on the right hand side of editor in which all occurrences of a selected item and all errors are marked with tiny small line (Gray, Red etc.) has been very useful for me in Large codes.

Do we have any plugin for VStudio to do that in C++ editor?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like `rock scroll`? I think it is in the productivity power tools now. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Comment: Anotations are at the left and right of the editor (narrow bars) in this image: http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/sarmadys/eclipse-1.jpg

Comment: @RedX: I guess the best available option is Productivity Power Tools at the time being. 

However, their implementation only marks errors and other items after you pass through them slowly in the editor (so that it can find and mark errors). It will not mark them outright.

Comment: I would guess that it marks them after intellisense has found them. This can take some time depending on the project size. If you miss bookmarks, VS has them also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "Microsoft Productivity Power Tools" is the only available option for Visual Studio 2010.

[Microsoft Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)